# Pytorch: Sparse Matrix multiplcation

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, pytorch

Given:

```
self.A = torch.autograd.Variable(random_sparse(n = dim)) 
self.w = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.Tensor(np.random.normal(0,1,(dim,dim))))
```

Goal1:

```
torch.mm(self.A, self.w)
```

Goal2:

```
torch.spmm(self.A, self.w)
```

Result1:

```
TypeError: Type torch.sparse.FloatTensor doesn't implement stateless method addmm
```

Result2:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spmm'
```

My PyTorch version is 0.1.12_2 - would greatly appreciate possible solutions.

Comment: Hi, could you maybe clarify (i.e. post code/ abbreviated code) what random_sparse does please so I can reproduce the error? Thanks!

Comment: @mexmex - `random_sparse` just creates a sparse matrix with random entries..could be any sparse matrix:).

Comment: I see. Sorry, I wasn't able to make much progress on this. I noticed it works if A and w are tensors, but not Variables( ), which gives rise to your first error. I think compatibility of sparse is still very limited, because the API is still experimental. But I'm afraid that doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

`spmm` has been moved from `torch` module to `torch.sparse` module. For official documentation please check this [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html#torch.sparse.FloatTensor.spmm). There is also a warning in the beginning of the documentation of `torch.sparse` module:

> This API is currently experimental and may change in the near future.